# Problem with updating user using keycloak rest api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a problem with updating user using keycloak rest api, neither my requests work.

For example, I'm trying to get all realm users based on [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/#_users_resource). I send get-request on this endpoint

```
http://keycloak.my/auth/realms/my_realm/account/users
```

but get 404 error

How to make it work? Why do I get 404, if I take this endpoint from docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL:

http://keycloak.my/auth/realms/my_realm/account/users

is incorrect.

The correct one is:

http://keycloak.my/auth/admin/realms/my_realm/account/users

For all those endpoints the base URL is `${KeycloakIP}/auth/admin/`